# How to make android WebView to download file from php based on header content type

Tags: php, android, excel, webview, download

I am having a lot of trouble with my lack of java knowledge on how to start a file download from a website that I developed in php.

I use an unusual way to download the file from my php as it is a custom Excel or Word file (thanks to PHPSpreadsheet and PHPWord), here is the code:

Word download :

```php
////save as a file in temp file
$temp_file = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), 'PHPWord');
$templateProcessor->saveAs($temp_file);

//EXPORT WORD PART
header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document');
//regardless of what it's named on the server 
$filename = "Contrat " . $typeclient . " client " . $array_site[1] . ".docx";
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=" . $filename);

//Read temp file
readfile($temp_file); //or echo file_get_contents($temp_file);
unlink($temp_file);  //remove temp file

exit();
```

Excel download :

```php
$temp_excel = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), 'PHPSpreadsheet');
$writer->save($temp_excel);
//set the header first, so the result will be treated as an xlsx file
header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
//make it an attachment so we can define filename
$filename = 'Chiffrage pour ' . $array_site[1] . '.xlsx';
header('Content-Disposition: attachement;filename=' . $filename);
//Read temp file to save it
readfile($temp_excel);
unlink($temp_excel);

exit();
```

Moreover, I tried to solve the problem by grabbing some parts of code already available on the internet, here is what my java android application currently contains :

Inside onCreate :

```java
        webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        webView.setDownloadListener(new DownloadListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDownloadStart(String url, String userAgent, String contentDisposition, String mimeType, long contentLength) {
                DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(url));

                request.setMimeType(mimeType);
                //------------------------COOKIE!!------------------------
                String cookies = CookieManager.getInstance().getCookie(url);
                request.addRequestHeader("cookie", cookies);
                //------------------------COOKIE!!------------------------
                request.addRequestHeader("User-Agent", userAgent);
                request.setDescription("Downloading file...");
                request.setTitle(URLUtil.guessFileName(url, contentDisposition, mimeType));
                request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
                request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
                request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, URLUtil.guessFileName(url, contentDisposition, mimeType));
                DownloadManager dm = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
                dm.enqueue(request);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Downloading File", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
```

For the moment, the Excel file downloads as the .php script that generates it, however when I rename the .php to .xlsx everything works, so Java doesn't seem to like my header from what I understand.
As for the Word, my android app returns "Downloading File" but nothing happens.

Obviously downloading to my android tablet from Google Chrome for example works perfectly, it would annoy me to have to revise my download method but if it turns out to be unavoidable then, why not

Thanks in advance to all of you and have a great day